# AutoCAD Plugin - Developer Symbols Registration

Tags: autocad, autodesk, objectarx

I've developed a plug-in using the ObjectARX SDK, C# and the Autodesk plug-in templates for VS2010. The plug-in is loaded into AutoCAD at start-up via a registry entry as documented in the SDK files.

The plug-in itself is to be distributed privately and will not be submitted to the 'Marketplace' supplied by Autodesk for AutoCAD products.

I've noticed that there is a section on the AutoDesk website with regards to registering a custom prefix via the [RDS scheme](http://usa.autodesk.com/adsk/servlet/index?siteID=%E2%80%8B123112&id=1075006).

Code that differs from the default template is found within the following areas:

- Namespaces e.g. "MyNamespace.Utility"
- Custom Classes MyClass.cs
- Custom Functions e.g. LogData()
- Custom Commands e.g. "DEBUGDATA"

Based on the current implementation and intended usage/distribution method is symbol registration required? I ask as I am not sure what would happen if another plug-in used by the user has a "DEBUGDATA" command for example.

If symbol registration is required where can I find a clear example of it's implementation within code?

Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way I try to avoid command name duplication is to use a really long command name, including my top namespace ("CadBloke" in my case) and then add a command alias to the acad.pgp file so the keyboard command is more sensible. Buttons on a toolbar etc don't care how long a command name is.

In your code, namespace clashes can certainly be an issue. I tend to make my top-level namespace pretty wordy, something like "CadBloke.CadTools.ToolName". You'd have to be pretty unlucky, or have annoyed someone, to get a clash with that sort of thing.

I saw your [question on the Autodesk forum](http://forums.autodesk.com/t5/NET/RDS-Usage-and-Guidelines/m-p/3561244) - that answer is basically the same as mine: try to make your namespace unique.

Hazy memory: I think some of the project wizards from Autodesk add your symbol to the namespace.

Here's a blog post with a link or 2 on symbol registration: http://adndevblog.typepad.com/autocad/2012/05/registered-developer-symbols.html (your link is dead, pretty typical of Autodesk as they move links around a lot). Follow that up and try & find some info on symbols. Good luck with that, I never found anything concrete. Me, I don't use it presently.

Comment: I'm struggling to see how registering symbols and adding them to the code will stop clashes - does AutoCAD check a web server for definitions?

Comment: Compiled classes are referenced all the way up to the top namespace which is "CadBloke" in my case or starts with your 4-letter symbol if that's the way you want to do it. In code the "using" or "Imports" sets the compiler's assumption as to which namespace you're using in a certain code file, after you add a reference to the namespace to your project.

If you have 2 classes with the same name in a code file you need to differentiate them using their namespaces up their respective trees until they are different.

Comment: as far as clashes caused by somebody else using your symbol letter, no, there is no external check. Autodesk didn't think of that, amongst other things like try...catch (a whole other topic).